# Marketing Cloud - email predictive content link broken after clicking multiple times

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, email-studio, einstein-recommendations

we implemented an abandoned cart journey builder which triggers an email.

It contains a predictive content which recommends 4 products.

Each product links the relative web page.

The problem is that some times it links a different page (for instance clicking on the first product displays the third product page).

We experienced this issue on different brand new browsers/OS/machine so we could not blame cache as stated by the marketing cloud support.

Does anyone has got the same problem or has got an idea on how to fix it?

Thank you